# How can I view each individual item of a nodeset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing XML from an API and displaying them on one page, though I have paginated them to 30 per page.

I want to view each one individually by using the `link_to` method and then update the attributes, which, in turn, can then be sent back to the API in XML. What I am not doing though is saving to a model, just displaying. Can I treat the returned results as objects?

This is the XML:

```
<entry>
<id>xxx</id>
<updated>xxx</updated> 
<category  scheme="xxx"  term="xxx"/>
<title type="text">xxx</title>
<link rel="xxx" type="xxx"    href="xxx"/> 
<link rel="xxx"/>     
<link rel="xx" type="xxx" href="xxx"/> <link rel="xx" type="axx" href="xxx"/> 
<gd:email rel="xxx" address="xxx" primary="xx"/> 
</entry>
```

This is the controller:

```
def show
  @contact = getcontact.find(params[:title])
end
```

This is the `getcontact` method:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open(url))
doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry[xmlns:title[node()]]')
```

This is the route:

```
match 'contacts/xmlns:title' => 'contacts#show'
```

The All Contacts view:

```
<% @mycontacts.each do |c| %>
Name: <%= c.xpath('xmlns:title').text %>  
Email: <%= c.xpath('gd:email/@address').text %> 
<%= link_to "Update Contact", contact_path(c.xpath('xmlns:title').text) %></p> 

<% end %>
```

The Show view:

```
<%= @contact.xpath('xmlns:title') %>
<%= @contact.xpath('gd:email/@address') %>
```

When I click on a link to view an individual contact, I get an error message:

```
undefined method `xpath' for #<Enumerator:0x3cc6570>
```

---

EDIT:

Would it be better to save everything to a model, update within the application, then convert to XML and send it back? That seems a bit long winded but would it be the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would create a model encapsulating the API and your retrieval methods. Also, I would use [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) which is designed exactly for this use case. It will automatically do the conversions to and from XML. (Although if that is an RSS feed I'd probably use a [dedicated RSS parser](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/feed_parsing))

This separation won't be "long winded," in fact it will be cleaner and can be more efficient, as you can cache or even just [memoize](http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/09/20/a-guide-to-memoization/) in the model minimizing the amount of fetching you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking that there was a way to change the details of the XML on the fly, but you are right, get it in the model, it is cleaner. Ill get on the case with HTTParty